# Jpanel 2d array of objects drawing problem

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I am trying two draw a 2D array(dynamic) of random boxes with different colors,
this is the code:

Main.java

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
     CustomPanel f = new CustomPanel (4, 5);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
        frame.add(f);
        frame.setSize(1000, 1000);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

CustomPanel.java:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class CustomPanel extends JPanel {
    Drawable [][]boxes;

    public CustomPanel (int rows, int cols)
    {
        this.setLayout(null);
        boxes = new Drawable[rows][cols];
        Random rand = new Random();
        for(int i = 0 ; i < rows ; i ++)
        {
            for(int j = 0 ; j  < cols ; j++)
            {
                switch(rand.nextInt(3))
                {
                    case 0:
                        boxes [i][j] = new Box1();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        boxes [i][j] = new Box2();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        boxes [i][j] = new Box3();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Rectangle t = g.getClipBounds();
        int box_width = t.width/ this.boxes[0].length;
        int box_heigt = t.height/ this.boxes.length;

        for(int i = 0 ; i < this.boxes.length; i ++)
        {
            for(int j = 0 ; j < this.boxes[0].length; j++)
            {
                System.out.println("" + i + ":" + j);
                boxes [i][j].draw(i * box_width, j * box_heigt, box_width, box_heigt, g);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Drawable.java:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;

public interface Drawable {
    public abstract void draw(int x, int y, int width, int height, Graphics g);
}
```

Box1(Box2, Box3 are the same, just different colors):

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Box1 implements Drawable{
    public Box1 () { //default constructor
        
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(int x, int y, int width, int height, Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
    }
}
```

The problem is that some of the boxes do not appear at the panel at all(altought I do iterate over both rows and columns).
I debugged it but could not find out why it happens(it might be silly - i know)

[image: this is example for 4 rows and 5 column. the last column just does not draw]

Comment: Don't use `getClipBounds()`. It possible the panel could be repainted with different clip values.  Just use getWidth() and getHeight().

Comment: @camickr do you mean at `paintComponent ` ? how? I guess `this.getParent().getSize().width` ?

Comment: @camickr and the result still remains the same. any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Box1(Box2, Box3 are the same, just different colors):

Don't create separate classes, just pass the Color as a parameter.

> do you mean at paintComponent  ? how? I guess this.getParent().getSize().width ?

Yes, paintComponent().

No, you don't get the parent. You are doing custom painting on a JPanel. You want the width/height of the panel using the methods I suggested in my comment.

> The problem is that some of the boxes do not appear at the panel at all

You have your x/y values reversed when you paint each Box. The "i" variable represents the rows (or the y value) and the "j" variable represents the columns (or the x value).

So your logic should b:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < this.boxes.length; i ++)
{
    for(int j = 0 ; j < this.boxes[0].length; j++)
    {

        //boxes [i][j].draw(i * box_width, j * box_heigt, box_width, box_heigt, g);
        boxes [i][j].draw(j * box_width, i * box_heigt, box_width, box_heigt, g);
    }
}
```

instead of using the Array length property to control the rows/columns, why not just save the row/column parameters as variable in your class which might help make your code easier to read.

Comment: Thank you for all the recommendation. so silly from my site about the j and i, didn't pay enough attention to it.